# How to show current date with time AM PM and CST using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to show current Date with below format
7/28/2016 11:55:37 PM CST

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: jquery has no special date functions - you want a javascript solution, perhaps using moment.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date is object of Javascript, Jquery also uses object of javaScript. I hope below code will be usefull for your.

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return date.getMonth()+1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + "  " + strTime;
}

var d = new Date();
var e = formatDate(d);

alert(e);
```

Comment: For that you can use timzoneOffset() function ane you have to make object of key and value paired object for all timezone name...

Comment: You can modify my function code.. there is no policy of use code which shared in StackOverlow.

Comment: I have provided hint about gettimezone offest.. this is enough I think

Comment: why you are googling yourself? have you tried to get solution your self first?